# How do I make while loops terminate after using If/ elif statements in python?

Tags: python, while-loop

Im trying to make a while loop in python, but the loop keeps looping infinitely.

Here's what I have so far:

```
def pvalue(num):
    ans = ''
    while num > 0:
        if 1 <= num <= 9:
            ans += 'B'
            num -= 1
        if num >= 10:
            ans += 'A'
            num -= 10
    return ans
```

I want num to be returned as ans as follows:

if num is 5, I want ans to be BBBBB

if num is 10, ans is A

if num is  22, I want ans to be AABB.

Comment: break statement

Comment: where do I put it?

Comment: Also going by your logic, it should be `<= 9`. Otherwise infinite loop when 9 is the input.

Comment: What do you want your code to do exactly? As Walle said, you can use a break inside the if condition, however, I believe that your code could be cleaner and more pythonic... But I'd also need to know what you're trying to do

Comment: What do you want the code to do? What are you expecting?

This is a good exercise in basic design. Specify the expected behaviour for the different values that num can take.

Comment: If num is 11, I want ans to return AB. If num is 15, I want ans to be ABBBBB

Comment: I don't understand. The code works as expected. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to learn about the [break statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#break).

As for your code:

```
def pvalue(num):
    ans = ''
    while num > 0:
        if num >= 10:
            ans += 'A'
            num -= 10
        else:
            ans += 'B'
            num -= 1
    return ans
```

Is much better, the case when `num == 9` is now handled properly

Comment: I don't see how this is different from my code, other than using else instead of a second if statement.

Comment: @Miraj50 the loop is still infinite.

Comment: @newarsenic I copied and pasted your *edited* code and ran it for numbers in the range 0 to 29. I can't reproduce an infinite loop now.

Comment: well in your first version you wrote in the first if statement `1 <= num < 9 `, which didn't handle the case when `num == 9`. Anyway for your use, sub 10  until `num < 10` then sub one until 0, is much better exprimed like this. 
Although you could have written 2 loop, the first one for `num >= 10` and the second for `num` between 0 and 9

Answer (score 0):

Use the break statement to get out of the loop.

```
def pvalue(num):
    ans = ''
    while num > 0:
        if 1 <= num <= 9:
            ans += 'B'
            num -= 1
        if num >= 10:
            ans += 'A'
            num -= 10
        if num<=0:
            break
    return ans
```